# disabling hyperlink in displayTag

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl, displaytag

I am using displayTag table decorator to display my JSP page.

The page has a table with columns. One of the columns is Action which has 2 hyperlinks displayed. One is pay and the other is close. Each row will have 5 columns action being the last columns with hyperlinks.

This is the action display code in JSP

```
<display-el:column property="action" sortable="false" title=" "
                            class="defaultTextCentered" style="width:6%" sortName="action" />
```

Below is my decorator code

```
public String getAction() {
  renderPayLink();
}

private void renderPayLink() {
  decoratedVal.append("<a href=\"javascript:newPopup('");
  decoratedVal.append(getContextPath());
  decoratedVal.append("/abc/taxPaymentInternal.html?iSeqNo=");
  decoratedVal.append(abc.getISeqNumber());
  decoratedVal.append("&iPeriod=");
  decoratedVal.append(abc.getIDate());
  decoratedVal.append("', 800, 700)\" title=\"Pay\">Pay</a>");
  decoratedVal.append("&nbsp;&nbsp;");        
}
```

So the link when clicked will open a popup window and have the user enter couple of details and submit. While this popup is open I can still go to the main browser and click the pay again which refreshes the popup and make me resubmit the info again. I have to stop this happening by disabling the pay button once I click in the browser and then open the popup. How can I achieve this?

Replaced pay with

```
  decoratedVal.append("', 800, 700)\" title=\"Pay\" ");
  decoratedVal.append("onclick=\"this.setAttribute(");
  decoratedVal.append("\'style\', \'pointer-events:none; cursor:default;\'); this.setAttribute("); 
  decoratedVal.append("\'href\', \'\')\">Pay</a>");
  decoratedVal.append("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

Getting "Unable to get property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference" error from f12 debug.

```
   <a title="Pay" onclick="this.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events:none; cursor:default;'); this.setAttribute('href', '')" href="javascript:newPopup('/mei/invoicing/launchConfirmPaymentInternal.html?invoiceSeqNo=131946&amp;invoicePeriod=02-11-2017', 800, 700)">Pay</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to disable the `<a>` tag when you click on it.

#### Simple solution:

You could replace this line:

`decoratedVal.append("', 800, 700)\" title=\"Pay\">Pay</a>");`

with those:

```
decoratedVal.append("', 800, 700)\" title=\"Pay\")
decoratedVal.append("onclick=\"this.setAttribute(")
decoratedVal.append("\'style\', \'pointer-events:none; cursor:default;\'); this.setAttribute(");
decoratedVal.append("\'href\', \'\')\">Pay</a>");
```

Please note that the link will be available again on page refresh. If you need another way to activate it, you would need to do it manually.

#### More elegant solution:

If you have a stylesheet, like a CSS file, you could create this class there:

```
.disabledLink{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

And in the `onclick` event of your link tag, replace the `setAttribute` with `addClass('disabledLink')`. That also makes it easier to remove, with a `removeClass('disabledLink')`

Comment: I tried the setAttribute the 1st solution but it had no effect. I was able to goto main browser and refresh the popup.

Comment: Does the mouse cursor changes after you click for the first time? After the popup opens, you should not see the little hand anymore...

Comment: yes mouse cursor changes and replaced with arrow mark. However it lets me click the link there.

Comment: Hmm...I updated the answer to also `setAttribute` of the `href`. Does that work?

Comment: decoratedVal.append("', 800, 700)\" title=\"Pay\" id=\"payLink\" ") ;
            decoratedVal.append("onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'payLink\').disabled = true;");
            decoratedVal.append("\">Pay</a>");

Comment: I added the disabled script as above which disables the link first time though. Since the table is a list each row holds the same id name and it doesnt work when i click say 2nd records "Pay"

Comment: tried setAttribute on href but still able to click on the hyperlink and resubmit.

Comment: Oh....that makes a big difference! You have multiple links. Updated the answer again. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194084/discussion-between-bruno-monteiro-and-jnpw).

Comment: @ Bruno Monteiro chat is disabled for me

Comment: Hmm weird...that was an automated message from StackOverflow. Anyway, I updated the answer again. The fact that you have multiple links change everything. Sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: tried the new update, still 1st click its disabled and then it lets you submit again.

Comment: Could you post the final generated HTML? That may help understand the issue.

Comment: updated with my recent edit. getting error on f12 debug

Comment: Thanks. But do you have the actual HTML code that was generated? I just wanted to check what all those `decoratedVal.append` are generating.

Comment: My bad...you can't update 2 attributes at the same time. I updated the answer again. Hope it helps you :)
The change is basically to separate both `setAttribute()` calls.

Comment: @ Bruno Monteiro Updated the code. Doesnt work. getting 400 while i click href

Answer (score 0):

try autolink
<display:column autolink="false">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).